# Remove client Information in OpenVpn

Tags: networking, openvpn

I use script to create OpenVpn Server and the connection Create for client I found OpenVpn never clear the Client Ip Address from Packets and The Sites Can easily find my real IP Address and Geo Location! so how can I remove this information :
example :
My OpenVpn Server is : 5.X.X.X
My Client Ip is : 1.X.X.X

if I connected Into OpenVpn Server :
The result Showed in https://www.iplocation.net/ is 5.X.X.X but if I use this script in php :

```
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
            $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
        } elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
            $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
        } else {
            $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        }
```

it will be show me 1.X.X.X that is my client ip address!
The script I use is : https://github.com/angristan/openvpn-install

Comment: Do you have complete and total control over the OpenVPN server configuration?

Comment: Yes I have the server.